# How to write a action to a particular button to select a particular rows of jlabels i have created here in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am new to java please help me i have a doubt.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import static javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author lenovo
 */
public class New1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JLabel a = new JLabel();
    JLabel b = new JLabel();
    /**
     * Creates new form New1
     */
    private ImageIcon abc = new ImageIcon("E:\\img1.png");
    private ImageIcon ab = new ImageIcon("E:\\img3.png");
    private ImageIcon abcd = new ImageIcon("E:\\img2.png");
    private ImageIcon abe = new ImageIcon("E:\\img4.png");
    private ImageIcon right = new ImageIcon("E:\\right.png");
    private ImageIcon down = new ImageIcon("E:\\down.png");

    public New1() {
        initComponents();

        insert();
        it();
        it1();
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    public void insert() {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            JLabel b = new JLabel(" " + i);
            JLabel a = new JLabel(" " + i);

            x = 10 + i % 10 * 40;
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                y = y + 40;
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                a.setText("0" + i);
                b.setText("0" + i);
                if (i >= 10) {
                    a.setText("" + i);
                    b.setText("" + i);
                }
                a.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
                b.setIcon(abc);
                b.addMouseListener((new MouseAdapter() {
                    int clicked = 1;

                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                            String r = b.getText();

                            String m = String.valueOf(clicked++);
                            b.setText(r);

                            b.setHorizontalTextPosition(CENTER);
                            b.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));

                            a.setText(m);
                            b.setIcon(ab);
                            // a.setVerticalTextPosition(CENTER);
                            // a.setHorizontalTextPosition(CENTER);
                            //  a.setVerticalTextPosition(BOTTOM);
                            // a.setVerticalTextPosition(BOTTOM);
                            a.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
                            a.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
                            a.setVisible(true);
                            a.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
                            javax.swing.border.Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(51, 51, 255), 1);
                            a.setBorder(border);
                        }
                        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                            String m = ("");
                            a.setText(m);
                            clicked = 1;
                        }

                    }
                }));
                javax.swing.border.Border border
                        = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(51, 51, 255), 1);
                a.setBorder(border);

            } else {
                a.setText("0" + i);
                b.setText("0" + i);

                if (i >= 10) {
                    a.setText("" + i);
                    b.setText("" + i);
                }
                a.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
                b.setIcon(abcd);
                b.addMouseListener((new MouseAdapter() {
                    int clicked = 1;

                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {

                            String m = String.valueOf(clicked++);
                            String w = b.getText();
                            b.setText(w);
                            b.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
                            b.setHorizontalTextPosition(CENTER);

                            a.setText(m);
                            b.setIcon(abe);
                            a.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
                            a.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
                            a.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
                            a.setVisible(true);
                            // javax.swing.border.Border border = 
                            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(51, 51, 255), 1);
                            //a.setBorder(border);

                        }
                        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                            String m = ("");
                            a.setText(m);
                            clicked = 1;

                        }

                    }

                }));

                //a.setIcon(abcd);
                javax.swing.border.Border border
                        = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(51, 51, 255), 1);
                a.setBorder(border);

            }

            a.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
            b.setBounds(x, y, 40, 40);
            a.setBounds(x, y, 40, 40);
            add(a);
            add(b);

        }

    }

    public void it() {
        int x = 410;
        int y = 10;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            JButton c = new JButton("");
            // x=410+i%410*40;
            y = 10 + j % 10 * 40;
            c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String ss = a.getText();
                    int nn = Integer.parseInt(ss);
                    if (nn < 1) {
                        a.setIcon(down);
                        b.setIcon(down);
                    }

                }

            });

            if (j % 1 == 0) {
                x = 410;
                y = y + 40;
            }

            c.setBounds(x, y, 40, 40);
            c.setIcon(right);

            add(c);

        }
    }

    public void it1() {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 450;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            JButton sr = new JButton("");
            x = 10 + i % 10 * 40;
            y = 450;
            sr.setBounds(x, y, 40, 40);
            sr.setIcon(down);
            add(sr);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(New1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(New1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(New1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(New1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new New1().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: please indent your code properly.

Comment: We have no idea what that code does. So the simple answer is add an `ActionListener` to your `JButton`.